# Can't find Path when not at LocalHost

Tags: .net, wcf, localhost

I am using WCF. When I start the application using localhost, I can get this Path:

```
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\..\..\Version.txt");
```

My URL was:

```
http://localhost:4426/MyService.svc
```

But when I change my "ServiceHost Uri" to my computer host name, the WCF can't find de path!

```
http://myhost:4426/MyService.svc
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping "myhost"? if not you can add "myhost" in your host file so it will know which ip to resolve when requesting "myhost".

Comment: But it must resolve with your pc public ip where the LocalHost do not, it need to go further on the network and so it might cause permission or restriction issue. Does it generate error? if yes can you post error message and stack trace?